# How to receive USB device attached broadcast in Android Xamarin?

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I am trying to receive USB attached Broadcast events on my app with this code, I registered the IntentFilter statically and went an extra mile to register the Receiver and the IntentFilter in the OnCreate method of my MainActivity, however when I connect a USB cable to from my phone to my laptop, it does not call the code inside the OnReceive which is supposed to show a Toast. Help me find a workaround to this.

***Manifest file with meta data***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0" 
          package="com.companyname.poc">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
     <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity android:name="MainActivity">
          <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
          
      </activity>
      
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

****device_filter.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="1234" product-id="5678" class="255" subclass="66" protocol="1" />
</resources>
```

***MainActivity.cs***

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            main = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            UsbManager usbManager=(UsbManager)GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(UsbManager.ExtraPermissionGranted), 0);
            //create a new instanceof usb reciever
            UsbReceiver usbReceiver = new UsbReceiver();
            //register the broadcast event receiver
            RegisterReceiver(usbReceiver, new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached)); 
}
```

Below is how I extended the BroadcastReceiver class to implement a listener for a USB device attached event.

***BroadcastReceiver***

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled=true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] {UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached })]
    public class UsbReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if(intent.Action==UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached)
            {
                UsbDevice device= (UsbDevice) intent.GetParcelableExtra(UsbManager.ExtraDevice);
                //request for permission to access thr udb device
                Toast.MakeText(context,"Usb device attached",ToastLength.Short).Show(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you set the manifest? refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host

Comment: Looks like I did not specify the meta files references, can you post an answer on hot to add the meta data to xamarin android

Comment: Added the manifest, still not working

Comment: The OnReceive not fire?

Comment: Yes, I pasted the meta data tags exactly as instructed on the official android dev page but I got nothing